# Apache htaccess redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

about a year ago, I moved a whole website to a new server. I still have access to the old server (which has a lot of junk on it) and I would like to have the old site redirect to the new one (they have different domains). The old server is running Apache. I thought something like this could be done via the .htaccess file so I put the following as my .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 / http://newsite.com/
```

This did not work and, upon accessing the old site, I got a "500 Internal Server Error".

I would rather delete the files from the old server. The problem is, though, that I am afraid that (since they are ranked pretty high on Google) if someone clicks on a link to one of those files, he will just get a "404 File Not Found Error". I just want to edit the .htaccess so that every file path on it will redirect to the new site. If you know how to do that, please help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using mod_rewrite instead, assuming it is enabled on the old server:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301, L]
```

This preserves and appends the path to the new host